# Read xml with atrributes into treeview

Tags: c#, xml, treeview

I've been trying to read a XML into a treeView (and succeded for the most part), but there is one problem: when a tag has attributes, they aren't read and the tree view gets a node only containing the name of the XML tag, but not it's attributes: here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<skiu:ikunk xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <economicalOperator>
        <id>BGNCA00003003</id>
    </economicalOperator>
    <ikunk id="1">
        <number>4</number>
        <name>КИНГС ТАБАКО ИНТЕРНЕШЪНЪЛ ЕАД</name>
        <certProvider>BTRUST</certProvider>
        <certAuthSn>10221954</certAuthSn>
        <certPin>5244</certPin>
        <description>Кингс Табако BGNCA00003003</description>
    </ikunk>
    <controllers>
        <number>1</number>
        <name>PLC</name>
        <description>FatekPLC</description>
        <templateCode>1</templateCode>
    </controllers>
    <tags>
        <templateEntryCode>T_TN</templateEntryCode>
        <name>Пореден номер на транзакцията</name>
    </tags>
</skiu_x003A_ikunk>
```

and when i read it into the tree view i get almost everything as expected except for the attributes of every tag !

My question is how can i make the attributes show in their respective nodes , but withing brackets (), like this : n-th node text (n-th attribute text)

here is my reading of the code :

```
XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
                XmlNode xmlnode;
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(ofdXML.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                xmldoc.Load(fs);
                xmlnode = xmldoc.ChildNodes[1];
                treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xmldoc.DocumentElement.Name));
                TreeNode tNode;
                tNode = treeView1.Nodes[0];
                AddNode(xmlnode, tNode);
```

and the code to AddNode :

```
private void AddNode(XmlNode inXmlNode, TreeNode inTreeNode)
        {
            XmlNode xNode;
            TreeNode tNode;
            XmlNodeList nodeList;
            int i = 0;
            if (inXmlNode.HasChildNodes)
            {
                nodeList = inXmlNode.ChildNodes;
                for (i = 0; i <= nodeList.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    xNode = inXmlNode.ChildNodes[i];
                    inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xNode.Name));
                    tNode = inTreeNode.Nodes[i];
                    AddNode(xNode, tNode);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                inTreeNode.Text = inXmlNode.InnerText.ToString();
            }
        }
```

any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Are you still having this issue? Could you mark an accepted answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XmlNode has an *Attributes* collection you need to address. Children of XmlNode's are simply the XmlNodes within it.

Try something like this to add an attribute as a TreeNode.

```
if (inXmlNode.Attributes.Any()) {
    foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in inXmlNode.Attributes) {
        String displayName = String.Format("({0})", attribute.Name)
        inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(displayName));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
and you will see that Attributes are stored in the Attributes property, not the ChildNodes property, so if you check this collection as well you should solve your problem